# Cache object that is derived from an entity that is cached in Hibernate L2C

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

Consider the following code:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Foo {
  public @Id int id;
  public String bar;
}

public class FooDto {
  public String bar;
}

public class FooService {

  public FooDto getOne(int id) {
    return toDto(fooRepository.findOne(id));
  }

  public List<FooDto> getAll() {
    return fooRepositoy.findAll().stream()
      .map(this::toDto)
      .collect(toList());
  }

  private toDto(Foo foo) {
    FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
    fooDto.bar = foo.bar;
    return foo;
  }
}
```

The results of `findOne()` and `findAll()` are cached by Hibernate's second level entity and query cache.

I also want to cache the derived `FooDto` objects / the results of `getOne()` and `getAll()`. The objects must be updated whenever the entity in the L2C is updated.

My idea is to maintain the cache myself by hooking into `Foo`'s `@PostPersist`, `@PostUpdate` and `@PostRemove`. Is this viable?

Can this be done with Spring Cache? Or is there another good approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering more on a conceptual level, I am not a Spring or hibernate guru.

> My idea is to maintain the cache myself by hooking into Foo's @PostPersist, @PostUpdate and  @PostRemove. Is this viable?

This is not enough to guarantee data consistency.

Probably this will also tie your code to be able to run on a single JVM only.

There is also the assumption, that the database is only updated through hibernate or your application.

> Or is there another good approach to this?

If you rely on consistency, (better) don't do any own caching.

If consistency is not needed, better do it very simple and work with a cache that refreshes by itself after some time (TTL/expiry after write).

Besides that, I can understand the requirement and would like to see a good solution to it as well. However, it smells like adding too much complexity and do over engineering.

Comment: Yeah, I learned that rolling my own caching is a bad idea. I think using Spring Cache is the best solution but I haven't had the time to implement it yet.